# Dell SoundBar (USB) no longer works with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio

When I installed the SoundBar on my Windows 10 system, it worked perfectly for a month or so, but now it has stopped. I don't play sound very often, so I don't know if it just happened or occurred because of an (automatic) Windows 10 update. (I never had any other OS or Windows version on this system.)

The SoundBar works fine when I attach it to a Mac, so there's some evidence that it's not the hardware. On the Windows system, the light is on, so it's attached to USB. See this diagnostic:

[image: Dell SoundBar diagnostic]

I have "reinstalled" the driver, but my understanding is that there is no special driver, so I'm not sure what I can do. Even the Dell website shows no drivers to download.

My system has only USB3 ports, so I am unable to test it with USB2. It was working on USB3 before, anyway.

Ideas?

Comment: right click the sound bar and select uninstall, then reboot.

Comment: Did that (uninstall/reboot), multiple times. Upon reboot, exact same problem.